# Can you use javascript to find the URL's of images and then pass that info into coldfusion?

Tags: javascript, regex, image, url, coldfusion

Can you use javascript to find the URL's of images and then pass that info into coldfusion and not use regx inside CF or JS?

it seems to me that firefly can find all the get image URL's inside net tab just fine and the DOM understands what is an image object or image link.

Can I access that stack of information already sorted someplace else.

The code that creates the images looks like e=new L(f||"//chart.googleapis.com/chart"); and 
can be found at http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:SQNM&fstype=ii.

The goal is to use these charts for a quick reference at http://www.investingNideas.com

My old stand bye methods are cfhttp and two regex

script = REMatchNoCase(']*>[^<]*', objGet.FileContent) /> //gets scripts

finance = REMatchNoCase(']+>.+?', objGet.FileContent) />//gets divs

I was looking into javascript reflection or reflection inside of iframe.

thanks

Comment: It's not very clear to me exactly what you're trying to do.  Do you want to have some JS code on your page which fetches the google finance page and extracts the images from it, so you can include those images on your own page?

Comment: Hello??? Are you following this question anymore?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this, and it does work.  Hopefully my understanding of "work" is the same as yours.  There are a few tricks involved, because the images you need to access are produced by javascript rendering within the browser, so server-side screen-scraping would not suffice (unless things got really complicated, and I'm not going there).  Also, things are tricky because the content you need loaded is on a remote domain (www.google.com) and that means there are restrictions on how you can access that content within the browser (can't really do this via Ajax without proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers on the google server; can't access this by embedding a direct iframe for similar restrictions preventing cross-domain DOM manipulation).  So, I had to work around both of those limitations.  One note - I realize you didn't ask for jQuery, but it honestly makes life so much easier here that I went ahead and used it.  So here's how I got it working:

index.cfm

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
        $("#googleFrame").load(function () { // bind to the load event, so we'll know that the embedded resources will all have finished rendering (including the images we're after)

                // this will simply include the images from google on the current page
                $("#rippedGoogleImages")
                   .html('') // remove the loading message
                   .append($(this).contents().find("img.goog-serverchart-image")); // pull the loaded images out of the frame

                // if you just want to see the URLs of those images:
                /* $(this).contents().find("img.goog-serverchart-image").each(function (){
                    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
                });
                */

        });
        $("#googleFrame").attr("src", "googleProxy.cfm"); // trickiness that will become clear below
});
</script>

<iframe id="googleFrame" style="display:none"></iframe><!-- hidden iframe -->

<h1>Finance Images</h1>

<div id="rippedGoogleImages">
Loading Images From Google...
</div>
```

And the key that allows us to get around cross-domain restrictions, a file that performs the direct request to google on the server: googleProxy.cfm:

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:SQNM&fstype=ii">

<cfoutput>
#cfhttp.filecontent#
</cfoutput>
<!--- The next line injects the necessary base href to allow the resources (js, css, images, etc...) to resolve correctly when served from this new location --->
<cfhtmlhead text="<base href='http://www.google.com/finance/'>">
```

All accomplished without nasty server-side screen scraping or regular expressions.

Comment: I hope it's clear that if you need those URL values back on the server-side (in CF), you could easily post them back with Ajax (among other means).  Let me know if you need that and aren't sure how to do it.